# How do I insert front matter in latexpdf output in Sphinx

Tags: pdf-generation, python-sphinx, pdflatex, tableofcontents, toctree

We are considering using Sphinx where I work and it appears to do everything we need.  However, I am having issues getting it to match the required corporate template, which requires there to be some front matter pages inserted between the title page and table of contents.

If text is text is placed above the master table of contents in the .rst file, then it is placed above the TOC in the HTML output, but it is moved to below the TOC in the pdf output.  I've also tried adding a hidden toc, but that didn't work either.  The content also gets placed after the non-hidden toc.

```
.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   frontmatter


.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   contents_of_document
```

I know this has to be possible since people have published books using this tool, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried this with sphinx 1.4.0 and 1.4.1.  Is this something I need to add a latex sty or cls file to make it work?  I would prefer not to since we would like to use both the HTML and PDF outputs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I need to RTFM.  It is in chapter 10 to of the sphinx manual:

> ’tableofcontents’ “tableofcontents”  call,  default ’\tableofcontents’.   Override  if you want to generate a different table of contents or put content between the title page and the TOC.

So it order to do this, you need to learn some LaTeX as you will have to manually (or programmatically) write the from matter separately from the reST documentation.

Comment: It'd still be nice to do what you were trying to do for multi-target builds that were trying to go to LaTeX and ePub and HTML, for instance.